# Create cells and wrap in parent every Nth iteration

Tags: javascript, wordpress, rest, loops, modulo

Recently I created a tool in order to take advantage of the REST-API in Wordpress, rather than the loop, in order to create a layout of my displayed blog.

So far so good, the problem is that my **loop** was pretty nice and sophisticated, so I was able to close the **row tag every 3 columns** so I could wrap my columns in a nice **3 columns layout**.

With php I did the following:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query(); 
while ($the_query->have_posts()) :
    $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php
    if ((($the_query->current_post+1) % 3 == 0) && ($the_query->current_post+1 !== count($the_query->posts))):
        echo "</div><div class='row'>";

    endif;
endwhile;
?>
```

Now with the rest api is a different story. My loop is something like that:

After I run the ajax function to display my post, I'm gonna do something like that to display them:

```
function create_post_list(object) {
  $('.content').append('<div class="row"></div>');
  var new_loop_js;

  for(var i=0; i<object.length; i++) {
    new_loop_js =
    '<div class="col-md-3">' +
    '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="' + object[i].id + '">' +
    object[i].title.rendered +
    '</a>' +
    '</div>';

    $('.content .row').append(nav_list_item);
  }
}
```

Any idea on how to make a modulo calculation, so that every 3 columns I can close my DIV `.row` and open another one - to wrap three other child elements?

Probably something like this?

```
if ( i == 2 ) {
  new_loop_js += '</div><div class="row">';
}
```

Or using modulo like in PHP? (both of them didn't work):

```
if ( i+1 % 3 == 0) {
  nav_list_item += '</div><div class="row">';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is:

```
if ( i > 0   &&   i % 3 === 0 )  {  /*CLOSE,OPEN ROW*/ }
/*CONCATENATE CELLS HERE*/
```

So, beside the wrong `i+1 % 3 == 0` it doesn't work cause you're appending something that **does not exists**: `nav_list_item`... or it's `new_loop_js`?
Don't append to DOM inside for loops. It's an extremely exhaustive operation. Build your items and than append the final concatenated HTML string **only once**.

### Using a `for` loop and string concatenation:

```js
function create_post_list( posts ) {
  
  var HTML = '<div class="row">'; // Init row
  
  for(var i=0; i<posts.length; i++) {
  
    if(i>0 && i%3===0) { // Close row if: not first iteration and i MOD 3 == 0
      HTML += '</div><div class="row">';
    }
  
    HTML += '<div class="col-md-3"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="'+ posts[i].id + '">' +
    posts[i].title.rendered + '</a></div>';
  }
  
  HTML += '</div>'; // Close row
  
  $('.content').append( HTML ); // Append only once
}

var queryPosts = [
  {id:1, title:{rendered:"Foo"}},
  {id:2, title:{rendered:"Bar"}},
  {id:3, title:{rendered:"Baz"}},
  {id:4, title:{rendered:"Faz"}},
  {id:5, title:{rendered:"Zab"}},
  {id:6, title:{rendered:"Fab"}},
  {id:7, title:{rendered:"Arb"}},
  {id:8, title:{rendered:"Bra"}},
]
create_post_list(queryPosts);
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

.row {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background:#aaa;
  margin: 10px;
}

.col-md-3 {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 20px;
  background:#ddd;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>
```

You can do is also with **functional** approach. Here's an **ES6**-fashion way:

### Using Array, `.map()`, `.concat()`, arrow functions, Template literals

```js
const create_post_list = posts => {

  const htmlArr = [].concat(
    `<div class="row">`,
    posts.map((ob, i) => `
      ${ i>0 && i%3===0 ? `</div><div class="row">` : '' }
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <a href="javascript:;" data-id="${ ob.id }">
            ${ ob.title.rendered }
          </a>
        </div>
    `),
    `</div>`
  );

  $('.content').append(htmlArr.join(""));
}


let queryPosts = [
  {id:1, title:{rendered:"Foo"}},
  {id:2, title:{rendered:"Bar"}},
  {id:3, title:{rendered:"Baz"}},
  {id:4, title:{rendered:"Faz"}},
  {id:5, title:{rendered:"Zab"}},
  {id:6, title:{rendered:"Fab"}},
  {id:7, title:{rendered:"Arb"}},
  {id:8, title:{rendered:"Bra"}},
];
create_post_list(queryPosts);
```

```css
/*QuickReset*/*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

.row {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #aaa;
  margin: 10px;
}

.col-md-3 {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Great Answer! The E6 Side.. I should really switch to this pathway.. Anyway.. Just great, and thanks, it worked

Comment: @Matto you're welcome. Frankly I appreciate more the good ol' fashioned way. *If a kid can read it - must be good*. ;) ES6... yah... probably not the best use case since the at-first-glance cryptic appearance - but useful nonetheless.